# Display buttons in one line no matter what size is the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display 4 pictures on a website, each one has different description below it. And there is a button at the end bottom. Since each picture has different description, it means amount of lines differs, but the size of div should be the same and button position should be in one line with all buttons of other pictures. Please see attached image to know what I mean.

I want to display the buttons in the same line with the last picture on right "Andy Clarke". So that when I resize page it won't mess them up.

[image]

Please help!

Code is:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit
}

html {
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

body {
  margin: 0
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block
}

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0
}

[hidden],
template {
  display: none
}

a {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline-width: 0
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration: underline dotted
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000
}

small {
  font-size: 80%
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em
}

figure {
  margin: 1em 40px
}

img {
  border-style: none
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em
}

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0
}

optgroup {
  font-weight: bold
}

button,
input {
  overflow: visible
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none
}

button,
html [type=button],
[type=reset],
[type=submit] {
  -webkit-appearance: button
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0
}

button:-moz-focusring,
[type=button]:-moz-focusring,
[type=reset]:-moz-focusring,
[type=submit]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: .35em .625em .75em
}

legend {
  color: inherit;
  display: table;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto
}

.ppl-font {
  font-family: 'Simonetta';
  font-size: 18px;
}

[type=checkbox],
[type=radio] {
  padding: 0
}

[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto
}

[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  outline-offset: -2px
}

[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: inherit;
  opacity: 0.54
}

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  font: inherit
}


/* End extract */

html,
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24px
}

h4 {
  font-size: 20px
}

h5 {
  font-size: 18px
}

h6 {
  font-size: 16px
}

.w3-serif {
  font-family: serif
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 10px 0
}

.w3-wide {
  letter-spacing: 4px
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 20px 0
}

.w3-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -5px
}

a {
  color: inherit
}

.w3-btn,
.w3-button {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.w3-btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}

.w3-btn,
.w3-button {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none
}

.w3-disabled,
.w3-btn:disabled,
.w3-button:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.3
}

.w3-disabled *,
:disabled * {
  pointer-events: none
}

.w3-btn.w3-disabled:hover,
.w3-btn:disabled:hover {
  box-shadow: none
}

.w3-input {
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%
}

.w3-container:after,
.w3-container:before,
.w3-panel:after,
.w3-panel:before,
.w3-row:after,
.w3-row:before,
.w3-row-padding:after,
.w3-row-padding:before,
.w3-cell-row:before,
.w3-cell-row:after,
.w3-clear:after,
.w3-clear:before,
.w3-bar:before,
.w3-bar:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both
}

.w3-col,
.w3-half,
.w3-third,
.w3-twothird,
.w3-threequarter,
.w3-quarter {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.w3-col.s1 {
  width: 8.33333%
}

.w3-col.s2 {
  width: 16.66666%
}

.w3-col.s3 {
  width: 24.99999%
}

.w3-col.s4 {
  width: 33.33333%
}

.w3-col.s5 {
  width: 41.66666%
}

.w3-col.s6 {
  width: 49.99999%
}

.w3-col.s7 {
  width: 58.33333%
}

.w3-col.s8 {
  width: 66.66666%
}

.w3-col.s9 {
  width: 74.99999%
}

.w3-col.s10 {
  width: 83.33333%
}

.w3-col.s11 {
  width: 91.66666%
}

.w3-col.s12 {
  width: 99.99999%
}

@media (min-width:601px) {
  .w3-col.m1 {
    width: 8.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.m2 {
    width: 16.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.m3,
  .w3-quarter {
    width: 24.99999%
  }
  .w3-col.m4,
  .w3-third {
    width: 33.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.m5 {
    width: 41.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.m6,
  .w3-half {
    width: 49.99999%
  }
  .w3-col.m7 {
    width: 58.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.m8,
  .w3-twothird {
    width: 66.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.m9,
  .w3-threequarter {
    width: 74.99999%
  }
  .w3-col.m10 {
    width: 83.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.m11 {
    width: 91.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.m12 {
    width: 99.99999%
  }
}

@media (min-width:993px) {
  .w3-col.l1 {
    width: 8.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.l2 {
    width: 16.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.l3 {
    width: 24.99999%
  }
  .w3-col.l4 {
    width: 33.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.l5 {
    width: 41.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.l6 {
    width: 49.99999%
  }
  .w3-col.l7 {
    width: 58.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.l8 {
    width: 66.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.l9 {
    width: 74.99999%
  }
  .w3-col.l10 {
    width: 83.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.l11 {
    width: 91.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.l12 {
    width: 99.99999%
  }
}

.w3-content {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: auto
}

.w3-rest {
  overflow: hidden
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .w3-modal-content {
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: auto!important
  }
  .w3-modal {
    padding-top: 30px
  }
  .w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-dropdown-content,
  .w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-dropdown-content {
    position: relative
  }
  .w3-hide-small {
    display: none!important
  }
  .w3-mobile {
    display: block;
    width: 100%!important
  }
  .w3-bar-item.w3-mobile,
  .w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile,
  .w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile {
    text-align: center
  }
  .w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile,
  .w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-btn,
  .w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-button,
  .w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile,
  .w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-btn,
  .w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-button {
    width: 100%
  }
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .w3-modal-content {
    width: 500px
  }
  .w3-modal {
    padding-top: 50px
  }
}

@media (min-width:993px) {
  .w3-modal-content {
    width: 900px
  }
  .w3-hide-large {
    display: none!important
  }
  .w3-sidebar.w3-collapse {
    display: block!important
  }
}

@media (max-width:992px) and (min-width:601px) {
  .w3-hide-medium {
    display: none!important
  }
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
  .w3-sidebar.w3-collapse {
    display: none
  }
  .w3-main {
    margin-left: 0!important;
    margin-right: 0!important
  }
}

.w3-top,
.w3-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1
}

.w3-top {
  top: 0
}

.w3-bottom {
  bottom: 0
}

.w3-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2
}

.w3-display-topleft {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0
}

.w3-display-topright {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0
}

.w3-display-bottomleft {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0
}

.w3-display-bottomright {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0
}

.w3-display-middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.w3-row-padding,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-half,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-third,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-twothird,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-threequarter,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-quarter,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-col {
  padding: 0 8px
}

.w3-container,
.w3-panel {
  padding: 0.01em 16px
}

@keyframes w3-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg)
  }
}

@keyframes fading {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

.w3-animate-opacity {
  animation: opac 0.8s
}

.w3-animate-input {
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out
}

.w3-animate-input:focus {
  width: 100%!important
}

.w3-opacity,
.w3-hover-opacity:hover {
  opacity: 0.60
}

.w3-opacity-off,
.w3-hover-opacity-off:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

.w3-opacity-max {
  opacity: 0.25
}

.w3-opacity-min {
  opacity: 0.75
}

.w3-greyscale-max,
.w3-grayscale-max,
.w3-hover-greyscale:hover,
.w3-hover-grayscale:hover {
  filter: grayscale(100%)
}

.w3-greyscale,
.w3-grayscale {
  filter: grayscale(75%)
}

.w3-greyscale-min,
.w3-grayscale-min {
  filter: grayscale(50%)
}

.w3-sepia {
  filter: sepia(75%)
}

.w3-sepia-max,
.w3-hover-sepia:hover {
  filter: sepia(100%)
}

.w3-sepia-min {
  filter: sepia(50%)
}

.w3-tiny {
  font-size: 10px!important
}

.w3-small {
  font-size: 12px!important
}

.w3-medium {
  font-size: 15px!important
}

.w3-large {
  font-size: 18px!important
}

.w3-xlarge {
  font-size: 24px!important
}

.w3-xxlarge {
  font-size: 36px!important
}

.w3-xxxlarge {
  font-size: 48px!important
}

.w3-jumbo {
  font-size: 64px!important
}

.w3-left-align {
  text-align: left!important
}

.w3-right-align {
  text-align: right!important
}

.w3-justify {
  text-align: justify!important
}

.w3-center {
  text-align: center!important
}

.w3-border-0 {
  border: 0!important
}

.w3-border {
  border: 1px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-border-left {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-border-right {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-topbar {
  border-top: 6px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-bottombar {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-leftbar {
  border-left: 6px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-rightbar {
  border-right: 6px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-section,
.w3-code {
  margin-top: 16px!important;
  margin-bottom: 16px!important
}

.w3-margin {
  margin: 16px!important
}

.w3-margin-top {
  margin-top: 16px!important
}

.w3-margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 16px!important
}

.w3-margin-left {
  margin-left: 16px!important
}

.w3-margin-right {
  margin-right: 16px!important
}

.w3-padding-small {
  padding: 4px 8px!important
}

.w3-padding {
  padding: 8px 16px!important
}

.w3-padding-large {
  padding: 12px 24px!important
}

.w3-padding-16 {
  padding-top: 16px!important;
  padding-bottom: 16px!important
}

.w3-padding-24 {
  padding-top: 24px!important;
  padding-bottom: 24px!important
}

.w3-padding-32 {
  padding-top: 32px!important;
  padding-bottom: 32px!important
}

.w3-padding-48 {
  padding-top: 48px!important;
  padding-bottom: 48px!important
}

.w3-padding-64 {
  padding-top: 64px!important;
  padding-bottom: 64px!important
}

.w3-left {
  float: left!important
}

.w3-right {
  float: right!important
}

.w3-button:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ccc!important
}

.w3-transparent,
.w3-hover-none:hover {
  background-color: transparent!important
}

.w3-hover-none:hover {
  box-shadow: none!important
}


/* Colors */

.w3-amber,
.w3-hover-amber:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ffc107!important
}

.w3-aqua,
.w3-hover-aqua:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #00ffff!important
}

.w3-blue,
.w3-hover-blue:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #2196F3!important
}

.w3-light-blue,
.w3-hover-light-blue:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #87CEEB!important
}

.w3-brown,
.w3-hover-brown:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #795548!important
}

.w3-cyan,
.w3-hover-cyan:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #00bcd4!important
}

.w3-blue-grey,
.w3-hover-blue-grey:hover,
.w3-blue-gray,
.w3-hover-blue-gray:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #607d8b!important
}

.w3-green,
.w3-hover-green:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #4CAF50!important
}

.w3-light-green,
.w3-hover-light-green:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #8bc34a!important
}

.w3-indigo,
.w3-hover-indigo:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #3f51b5!important
}

.w3-khaki,
.w3-hover-khaki:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #f0e68c!important
}

.w3-lime,
.w3-hover-lime:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #cddc39!important
}

.w3-orange,
.w3-hover-orange:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ff9800!important
}

.w3-deep-orange,
.w3-hover-deep-orange:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #ff5722!important
}

.w3-pink,
.w3-hover-pink:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #e91e63!important
}

.w3-purple,
.w3-hover-purple:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #9c27b0!important
}

.w3-deep-purple,
.w3-hover-deep-purple:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #673ab7!important
}

.w3-red,
.w3-hover-red:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #f44336!important
}

.w3-sand,
.w3-hover-sand:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #fdf5e6!important
}

.w3-teal,
.w3-hover-teal:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #009688!important
}

.w3-yellow,
.w3-hover-yellow:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ffeb3b!important
}

.w3-white,
.w3-hover-white:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #fff!important
}

.w3-black,
.w3-hover-black:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #000!important
}

.w3-red,
.w3-hover-black:hover {
  color: red!important;
  background-color: #000!important
}

.w3-grey,
.w3-hover-grey:hover,
.w3-gray,
.w3-hover-gray:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #bbb!important
}

.w3-light-grey,
.w3-hover-light-grey:hover,
.w3-light-gray,
.w3-hover-light-gray:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #f1f1f1!important;
}

.w3-dark-grey,
.w3-hover-dark-grey:hover,
.w3-dark-gray,
.w3-hover-dark-gray:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #616161!important
}

.w3-pale-red,
.w3-hover-pale-red:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ffdddd!important
}

.w3-pale-green,
.w3-hover-pale-green:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ddffdd!important
}

.w3-pale-yellow,
.w3-hover-pale-yellow:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ffffcc!important
}

.w3-pale-blue,
.w3-hover-pale-blue:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ddffff!important
}

.w3-text-red,
.w3-hover-text-red:hover {
  color: #f44336!important
}

.w3-text-green,
.w3-hover-text-green:hover {
  color: #4CAF50!important
}

.w3-text-blue,
.w3-hover-text-blue:hover {
  color: #2196F3!important
}

.w3-text-yellow,
.w3-hover-text-yellow:hover {
  color: #ffeb3b!important
}

.w3-text-white,
.w3-hover-text-white:hover {
  color: #fff!important
}

.w3-text-op,
.w3-hover-text-op:hover {
  color: #a1a1a1!important
}

.w3-text-black,
.w3-hover-text-black:hover {
  color: #000!important
}

.w3-text-grey,
.w3-hover-text-grey:hover,
.w3-text-gray,
.w3-hover-text-gray:hover {
  color: #757575!important
}

.w3-text-amber {
  color: #ffc107!important
}

.w3-text-aqua {
  color: #00ffff!important
}

.w3-text-light-blue {
  color: #87CEEB!important
}

.w3-text-brown {
  color: #795548!important
}

.w3-text-cyan {
  color: #00bcd4!important
}

.w3-text-blue-grey,
.w3-text-blue-gray {
  color: #607d8b!important
}

.w3-text-light-green {
  color: #8bc34a!important
}

.w3-text-indigo {
  color: #3f51b5!important
}

.w3-text-khaki {
  color: #b4aa50!important
}

.w3-text-lime {
  color: #cddc39!important
}

.w3-text-orange {
  color: #ff9800!important
}

.w3-text-deep-orange {
  color: #ff5722!important
}

.w3-text-pink {
  color: #e91e63!important
}

.w3-text-purple {
  color: #9c27b0!important
}

.w3-text-deep-purple {
  color: #673ab7!important
}

.w3-text-sand {
  color: #fdf5e6!important
}

.w3-text-teal {
  color: #009688!important
}

.w3-text-light-grey,
.w3-hover-text-light-grey:hover,
.w3-text-light-gray,
.w3-hover-text-light-gray:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1!important
}

.w3-border-grey,
.w3-hover-border-grey:hover,
.w3-border-gray,
.w3-hover-border-gray:hover {
  border-color: #bbb!important
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container w3-padding-32" id="People">
  <h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey w3-padding-16">Interesting People Every Web Designer Should Know</h3>
</div>

<div class="w3-row-padding w3-grayscale">
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
    <img src="ppl1.jpg" alt="Ethan" style="width:100%">
    <h3>Ethan Marcotte</h3>
    <p class="w3-opacity">Founder of Responsive Web Design</p>
    <p class="ppl-font">
      If there's one man in the web industry who probably doesn't need an introduction, it's </br>Ethan Marcotte.</br>
      One of the web's best-known designers. </br>Ethan is a regular and popular speaker on the conference circuit and, in his own words, the one who "started that whole 'responsive web design' thing".
      <form>
        <input class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block" type="button" value="Click" onclick="window.open('https://ethanmarcotte.com/')" />
      </form>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
    <img src="ppl2.jpg" alt="Chris" style="width:100%">
    <h3>Chris Coyier</h3>
    <p class="w3-opacity">Founder / Writer / Designer</p>
    <p class="ppl-font">A world-known CSS expert and HTML guru, Chris Coyier writes one of the most popular CSS blogs on the web, CSS-Tricks. Throughout his career, Chris has published many tutorials, websites, and scripts to help designers improve their skills. A designer
      at CodePen, Chris can also be found at web design and development podcast ShopTalk.
      <form>
        <input class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block" type="button" value="Click" onclick="window.open('https://chriscoyier.net/')" />
      </form>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
    <img src="ppl3.jpg" alt="Karen" style="width:100%">
    <h3>Karen McGrane</h3>
    <p class="w3-opacity">UX and content strategy for web and mobile</p>
    <p class="ppl-font">
      UX expert Karen McGrane motto is simple - 'On a good day, I make the web more awesome. A content strategist and user experience designer, Karen has over 15 years experience of making big, complicated websites. Currently managing partner of Bond Art +
      Science, she is also the author of Content Strategy for Mobile.
      <form>
        <input class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block" type="button" value="Click" onclick="window.open('https://karenmcgrane.com/')" />
      </form>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
    <img src="ppl4.jpg" alt="Andy" style="width:100%">
    <h3>Andy Clarke</h3>
    <p class="w3-opacity">Founder of a Welsh-based design studio</p>
    <p class="ppl-font">Andy is a well-known speaker on the conference circuit, and is the founder of a Welsh-based design studio, Stuff and Nonsense, that boasts clients including the likes of The Home Office, STV and the International Organization for Standardization.
      Andy is perhaps best known for his book, Hardboiled Web Design, which combined the idea of progressive enhancement with responsive web design.
      <form>
        <input class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block div-size4" type="button" value="Click" onclick="window.open('https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/')" />
      </form>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Same line elements

**Setting a height to the text** that is displayed below the pictures should give a good height to put a button:

[image]

Example with scroll y overflow:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
.Card img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
}
.Card h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
/*Magic starts here*/
.Card p {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.Card button {
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="Card">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"/>
  <h1>Name</h1>
  <p>Text goes here, Text goes here, Text goes here, Text goes here, Text goes here, Text goes here, Text goes here, Text goes here, Text goes here, Text goes here, Text goes here, Text goes here,</p>
  <button>Press me!</button>
</div>
<div class="Card">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"/>
  <h1>Nameru</h1>
  <p>Text goes here</p>
  <button>Press me!</button>
</div>
<div class="Card">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"/>
  <h1>Nameru</h1>
  <p>Text goes here</p>
  <button>Press me!</button>
</div>
<div class="Card">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"/>
  <h1>Nameru</h1>
  <p>Text goes here</p>
  <button>Press me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: downside of this is that the css will have to include breakpoints to account for different heights at smaller screen sizes.

Comment: @TKoL how is height a problem on smaller screens? Shouldn't the "cards" just wrap if the browser screen is narrow?

Comment: I didn't see any reason to assume the cards are fixed-width. If they're not fixed-width, then the height of the text elements can change.

Comment: @TKoL i see and i agree if there not fixed width then that would happen. This answer is with a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading about how to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), or alternatively potenially using tables or `display:table`. Each of those can force your columns to be the same height, and you can then position your buttons at the bottom of each one.

[edit]
Here's a JSFiddle that shows how you can use it to smash the button to the bottom:
https://jsfiddle.net/hsnohum5/1/

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code into your CSS. I hope it will work.

```
.w3-row-padding {
  display: flex;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.w3-row-padding >div {
  position: relative;
}

.w3-row-padding >div>p {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without redoing the whole thing, I can come up with so called [padding trick](https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/). The idea is to set the height of the container to 0px and make padding look as if it is the height. Set `relative` position for this outer container as well. Also place another container inside it and set its position to `absolute` and stretch it to take all the space within the outer one. In your code I added `<div>` right inside `.w3-col` and placed all the content there. I set the following additional styles:

```
 .w3-col form {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
 }
 .w3-btn, .w3-button {
    width: 90%;
 }
 .w3-col {
    padding-bottom: 80%!important;
    position: relative;
    height: 0px;
 }
.w3-col > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If your blocks are static - which seems to be the case - you just need to set `padding-bottom` properly for `.w3-col` to fit all the content. The whole thing (you may want to polish responsiveness for different viewports):

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit
}

html {
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

body {
  margin: 0
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block
}

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline
}

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0
}

[hidden],
template {
  display: none
}

a {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline-width: 0
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration: underline dotted
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic
}

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000
}

small {
  font-size: 80%
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em
}

figure {
  margin: 1em 40px
}

img {
  border-style: none
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em
}

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible
}

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0
}

optgroup {
  font-weight: bold
}

button,
input {
  overflow: visible
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none
}

button,
html [type=button],
[type=reset],
[type=submit] {
  -webkit-appearance: button
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type=button]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0
}

button:-moz-focusring,
[type=button]:-moz-focusring,
[type=reset]:-moz-focusring,
[type=submit]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText
}

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: .35em .625em .75em
}

legend {
  color: inherit;
  display: table;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto
}

.ppl-font {
  font-family: 'Simonetta';
  font-size: 18px;
}

[type=checkbox],
[type=radio] {
  padding: 0
}

[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto
}

[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  outline-offset: -2px
}

[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: inherit;
  opacity: 0.54
}

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  font: inherit
}


/* End extract */

html,
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24px
}

h4 {
  font-size: 20px
}

h5 {
  font-size: 18px
}

h6 {
  font-size: 16px
}

.w3-serif {
  font-family: serif
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 10px 0
}

.w3-wide {
  letter-spacing: 4px
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 20px 0
}

.w3-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -5px
}

a {
  color: inherit
}

.w3-btn,
.w3-button {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 90%;
}
.w3-col form {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.w3-btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}

.w3-btn,
.w3-button {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none
}

.w3-disabled,
.w3-btn:disabled,
.w3-button:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.3
}

.w3-disabled *,
:disabled * {
  pointer-events: none
}

.w3-btn.w3-disabled:hover,
.w3-btn:disabled:hover {
  box-shadow: none
}

.w3-input {
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%
}

.w3-container:after,
.w3-container:before,
.w3-panel:after,
.w3-panel:before,
.w3-row:after,
.w3-row:before,
.w3-row-padding:after,
.w3-row-padding:before,
.w3-cell-row:before,
.w3-cell-row:after,
.w3-clear:after,
.w3-clear:before,
.w3-bar:before,
.w3-bar:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both
}
.w3-col {
    padding-bottom: 80%!important;
    position: relative;
    height: 0px;
}
.w3-col > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.w3-col,
.w3-half,
.w3-third,
.w3-twothird,
.w3-threequarter,
.w3-quarter {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.w3-col.s1 {
  width: 8.33333%
}

.w3-col.s2 {
  width: 16.66666%
}

.w3-col.s3 {
  width: 24.99999%
}

.w3-col.s4 {
  width: 33.33333%
}

.w3-col.s5 {
  width: 41.66666%
}

.w3-col.s6 {
  width: 49.99999%
}

.w3-col.s7 {
  width: 58.33333%
}

.w3-col.s8 {
  width: 66.66666%
}

.w3-col.s9 {
  width: 74.99999%
}

.w3-col.s10 {
  width: 83.33333%
}

.w3-col.s11 {
  width: 91.66666%
}

.w3-col.s12 {
  width: 99.99999%
}

@media (min-width:601px) {
  .w3-col.m1 {
    width: 8.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.m2 {
    width: 16.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.m3,
  .w3-quarter {
    width: 24.99999%
  }
  .w3-col.m4,
  .w3-third {
    width: 33.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.m5 {
    width: 41.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.m6,
  .w3-half {
    width: 49.99999%
  }
  .w3-col.m7 {
    width: 58.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.m8,
  .w3-twothird {
    width: 66.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.m9,
  .w3-threequarter {
    width: 74.99999%
  }
  .w3-col.m10 {
    width: 83.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.m11 {
    width: 91.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.m12 {
    width: 99.99999%
  }
}

@media (min-width:993px) {
  .w3-col.l1 {
    width: 8.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.l2 {
    width: 16.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.l3 {
    width: 24.99999%
  }
  .w3-col.l4 {
    width: 33.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.l5 {
    width: 41.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.l6 {
    width: 49.99999%
  }
  .w3-col.l7 {
    width: 58.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.l8 {
    width: 66.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.l9 {
    width: 74.99999%
  }
  .w3-col.l10 {
    width: 83.33333%
  }
  .w3-col.l11 {
    width: 91.66666%
  }
  .w3-col.l12 {
    width: 99.99999%
  }
}

.w3-content {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: auto
}

.w3-rest {
  overflow: hidden
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .w3-modal-content {
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: auto!important
  }
  .w3-modal {
    padding-top: 30px
  }
  .w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-dropdown-content,
  .w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-dropdown-content {
    position: relative
  }
  .w3-hide-small {
    display: none!important
  }
  .w3-mobile {
    display: block;
    width: 100%!important
  }
  .w3-bar-item.w3-mobile,
  .w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile,
  .w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile {
    text-align: center
  }
  .w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile,
  .w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-btn,
  .w3-dropdown-hover.w3-mobile .w3-button,
  .w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile,
  .w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-btn,
  .w3-dropdown-click.w3-mobile .w3-button {
    width: 100%
  }
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .w3-modal-content {
    width: 500px
  }
  .w3-modal {
    padding-top: 50px
  }
}

@media (min-width:993px) {
  .w3-modal-content {
    width: 900px
  }
  .w3-hide-large {
    display: none!important
  }
  .w3-sidebar.w3-collapse {
    display: block!important
  }
}

@media (max-width:992px) and (min-width:601px) {
  .w3-hide-medium {
    display: none!important
  }
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
  .w3-sidebar.w3-collapse {
    display: none
  }
  .w3-main {
    margin-left: 0!important;
    margin-right: 0!important
  }
}

.w3-top,
.w3-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1
}

.w3-top {
  top: 0
}

.w3-bottom {
  bottom: 0
}

.w3-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2
}

.w3-display-topleft {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0
}

.w3-display-topright {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0
}

.w3-display-bottomleft {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0
}

.w3-display-bottomright {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0
}

.w3-display-middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.w3-row-padding,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-half,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-third,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-twothird,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-threequarter,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-quarter,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-col {
  padding: 0 8px
}

.w3-container,
.w3-panel {
  padding: 0.01em 16px
}

@keyframes w3-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg)
  }
}

@keyframes fading {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

.w3-animate-opacity {
  animation: opac 0.8s
}

.w3-animate-input {
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out
}

.w3-animate-input:focus {
  width: 100%!important
}

.w3-opacity,
.w3-hover-opacity:hover {
  opacity: 0.60
}

.w3-opacity-off,
.w3-hover-opacity-off:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

.w3-opacity-max {
  opacity: 0.25
}

.w3-opacity-min {
  opacity: 0.75
}

.w3-greyscale-max,
.w3-grayscale-max,
.w3-hover-greyscale:hover,
.w3-hover-grayscale:hover {
  filter: grayscale(100%)
}

.w3-greyscale,
.w3-grayscale {
  filter: grayscale(75%)
}

.w3-greyscale-min,
.w3-grayscale-min {
  filter: grayscale(50%)
}

.w3-sepia {
  filter: sepia(75%)
}

.w3-sepia-max,
.w3-hover-sepia:hover {
  filter: sepia(100%)
}

.w3-sepia-min {
  filter: sepia(50%)
}

.w3-tiny {
  font-size: 10px!important
}

.w3-small {
  font-size: 12px!important
}

.w3-medium {
  font-size: 15px!important
}

.w3-large {
  font-size: 18px!important
}

.w3-xlarge {
  font-size: 24px!important
}

.w3-xxlarge {
  font-size: 36px!important
}

.w3-xxxlarge {
  font-size: 48px!important
}

.w3-jumbo {
  font-size: 64px!important
}

.w3-left-align {
  text-align: left!important
}

.w3-right-align {
  text-align: right!important
}

.w3-justify {
  text-align: justify!important
}

.w3-center {
  text-align: center!important
}

.w3-border-0 {
  border: 0!important
}

.w3-border {
  border: 1px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-border-left {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-border-right {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-topbar {
  border-top: 6px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-bottombar {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-leftbar {
  border-left: 6px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-rightbar {
  border-right: 6px solid #ccc!important
}

.w3-section,
.w3-code {
  margin-top: 16px!important;
  margin-bottom: 16px!important
}

.w3-margin {
  margin: 16px!important
}

.w3-margin-top {
  margin-top: 16px!important
}

.w3-margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 16px!important
}

.w3-margin-left {
  margin-left: 16px!important
}

.w3-margin-right {
  margin-right: 16px!important
}

.w3-padding-small {
  padding: 4px 8px!important
}

.w3-padding {
  padding: 8px 16px!important
}

.w3-padding-large {
  padding: 12px 24px!important
}

.w3-padding-16 {
  padding-top: 16px!important;
  padding-bottom: 16px!important
}

.w3-padding-24 {
  padding-top: 24px!important;
  padding-bottom: 24px!important
}

.w3-padding-32 {
  padding-top: 32px!important;
  padding-bottom: 32px!important
}

.w3-padding-48 {
  padding-top: 48px!important;
  padding-bottom: 48px!important
}

.w3-padding-64 {
  padding-top: 64px!important;
  padding-bottom: 64px!important
}

.w3-left {
  float: left!important
}

.w3-right {
  float: right!important
}

.w3-button:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ccc!important
}

.w3-transparent,
.w3-hover-none:hover {
  background-color: transparent!important
}

.w3-hover-none:hover {
  box-shadow: none!important
}


/* Colors */

.w3-amber,
.w3-hover-amber:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ffc107!important
}

.w3-aqua,
.w3-hover-aqua:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #00ffff!important
}

.w3-blue,
.w3-hover-blue:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #2196F3!important
}

.w3-light-blue,
.w3-hover-light-blue:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #87CEEB!important
}

.w3-brown,
.w3-hover-brown:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #795548!important
}

.w3-cyan,
.w3-hover-cyan:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #00bcd4!important
}

.w3-blue-grey,
.w3-hover-blue-grey:hover,
.w3-blue-gray,
.w3-hover-blue-gray:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #607d8b!important
}

.w3-green,
.w3-hover-green:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #4CAF50!important
}

.w3-light-green,
.w3-hover-light-green:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #8bc34a!important
}

.w3-indigo,
.w3-hover-indigo:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #3f51b5!important
}

.w3-khaki,
.w3-hover-khaki:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #f0e68c!important
}

.w3-lime,
.w3-hover-lime:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #cddc39!important
}

.w3-orange,
.w3-hover-orange:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ff9800!important
}

.w3-deep-orange,
.w3-hover-deep-orange:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #ff5722!important
}

.w3-pink,
.w3-hover-pink:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #e91e63!important
}

.w3-purple,
.w3-hover-purple:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #9c27b0!important
}

.w3-deep-purple,
.w3-hover-deep-purple:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #673ab7!important
}

.w3-red,
.w3-hover-red:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #f44336!important
}

.w3-sand,
.w3-hover-sand:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #fdf5e6!important
}

.w3-teal,
.w3-hover-teal:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #009688!important
}

.w3-yellow,
.w3-hover-yellow:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ffeb3b!important
}

.w3-white,
.w3-hover-white:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #fff!important
}

.w3-black,
.w3-hover-black:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #000!important
}

.w3-red,
.w3-hover-black:hover {
  color: red!important;
  background-color: #000!important
}

.w3-grey,
.w3-hover-grey:hover,
.w3-gray,
.w3-hover-gray:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #bbb!important
}

.w3-light-grey,
.w3-hover-light-grey:hover,
.w3-light-gray,
.w3-hover-light-gray:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #f1f1f1!important;
}

.w3-dark-grey,
.w3-hover-dark-grey:hover,
.w3-dark-gray,
.w3-hover-dark-gray:hover {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #616161!important
}

.w3-pale-red,
.w3-hover-pale-red:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ffdddd!important
}

.w3-pale-green,
.w3-hover-pale-green:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ddffdd!important
}

.w3-pale-yellow,
.w3-hover-pale-yellow:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ffffcc!important
}

.w3-pale-blue,
.w3-hover-pale-blue:hover {
  color: #000!important;
  background-color: #ddffff!important
}

.w3-text-red,
.w3-hover-text-red:hover {
  color: #f44336!important
}

.w3-text-green,
.w3-hover-text-green:hover {
  color: #4CAF50!important
}

.w3-text-blue,
.w3-hover-text-blue:hover {
  color: #2196F3!important
}

.w3-text-yellow,
.w3-hover-text-yellow:hover {
  color: #ffeb3b!important
}

.w3-text-white,
.w3-hover-text-white:hover {
  color: #fff!important
}

.w3-text-op,
.w3-hover-text-op:hover {
  color: #a1a1a1!important
}

.w3-text-black,
.w3-hover-text-black:hover {
  color: #000!important
}

.w3-text-grey,
.w3-hover-text-grey:hover,
.w3-text-gray,
.w3-hover-text-gray:hover {
  color: #757575!important
}

.w3-text-amber {
  color: #ffc107!important
}

.w3-text-aqua {
  color: #00ffff!important
}

.w3-text-light-blue {
  color: #87CEEB!important
}

.w3-text-brown {
  color: #795548!important
}

.w3-text-cyan {
  color: #00bcd4!important
}

.w3-text-blue-grey,
.w3-text-blue-gray {
  color: #607d8b!important
}

.w3-text-light-green {
  color: #8bc34a!important
}

.w3-text-indigo {
  color: #3f51b5!important
}

.w3-text-khaki {
  color: #b4aa50!important
}

.w3-text-lime {
  color: #cddc39!important
}

.w3-text-orange {
  color: #ff9800!important
}

.w3-text-deep-orange {
  color: #ff5722!important
}

.w3-text-pink {
  color: #e91e63!important
}

.w3-text-purple {
  color: #9c27b0!important
}

.w3-text-deep-purple {
  color: #673ab7!important
}

.w3-text-sand {
  color: #fdf5e6!important
}

.w3-text-teal {
  color: #009688!important
}

.w3-text-light-grey,
.w3-hover-text-light-grey:hover,
.w3-text-light-gray,
.w3-hover-text-light-gray:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1!important
}

.w3-border-grey,
.w3-hover-border-grey:hover,
.w3-border-gray,
.w3-hover-border-gray:hover {
  border-color: #bbb!important
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container w3-padding-32" id="People">
  <h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey w3-padding-16">Interesting People Every Web Designer Should Know</h3> 
</div>

<div class="w3-row-padding w3-grayscale">
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
  <div>
    <img src="ppl1.jpg" alt="Ethan" style="width:100%">
    <h3>Ethan Marcotte</h3>
    <p class="w3-opacity">Founder of Responsive Web Design</p>
    <p class="ppl-font">
      If there's one man in the web industry who probably doesn't need an introduction, it's </br>Ethan Marcotte.</br>
      One of the web's best-known designers. </br>Ethan is a regular and popular speaker on the conference circuit and, in his own words, the one who "started that whole 'responsive web design' thing".</p>
      <form>
        <input class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block" type="button" value="Click" onclick="window.open('https://ethanmarcotte.com/')" />
      </form>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom"><div>
    <img src="ppl2.jpg" alt="Chris" style="width:100%">
    <h3>Chris Coyier</h3>
    <p class="w3-opacity">Founder / Writer / Designer</p>
    <p class="ppl-font">A world-known CSS expert and HTML guru, Chris Coyier writes one of the most popular CSS blogs on the web, CSS-Tricks. Throughout his career, Chris has published many tutorials, websites, and scripts to help designers improve their skills. A designer
      at CodePen, Chris can also be found at web design and development podcast ShopTalk.</p> 
      <form>
        <input class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block" type="button" value="Click" onclick="window.open('https://chriscoyier.net/')" />
      </form>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom"><div>
    <img src="ppl3.jpg" alt="Karen" style="width:100%">
    <h3>Karen McGrane</h3>
    <p class="w3-opacity">UX and content strategy for web and mobile</p>
    <p class="ppl-font">
      UX expert Karen McGrane motto is simple - 'On a good day, I make the web more awesome. A content strategist and user experience designer, Karen has over 15 years experience of making big, complicated websites. Currently managing partner of Bond Art +
      Science, she is also the author of Content Strategy for Mobile.</p> 
      <form>
        <input class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block" type="button" value="Click" onclick="window.open('https://karenmcgrane.com/')" />
      </form>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom"><div>
    <img src="ppl4.jpg" alt="Andy" style="width:100%">
    <h3>Andy Clarke</h3>
    <p class="w3-opacity">Founder of a Welsh-based design studio</p>
    <p class="ppl-font">Andy is a well-known speaker on the conference circuit, and is the founder of a Welsh-based design studio, Stuff and Nonsense, that boasts clients including the likes of The Home Office, STV and the International Organization for Standardization.
      Andy is perhaps best known for his book, Hardboiled Web Design, which combined the idea of progressive enhancement with responsive web design.</p>
      <form>
        <input class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block div-size4" type="button" value="Click" onclick="window.open('https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/')" />
      </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```